# Live usb windows xp

Tags: windows, windows-xp, boot, usb, installation

I want to create a bootable usb that contains windows xp.I dont want to install it , i just want to boot it, but i have couple of problems. I tried to create live usb from full windows xp file (the one that is 700mb , and the reason why i choose it is because i need the full version of windows xp) but it didnt work (i tried it with 5 iso to usb softwares).Also the one that is booting from usb are 
not full , they are about 70 mbs.All the tutorials are only for windows xp installation from usb.Please help me i dont know what else to do.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think there is such a thing, at least officially, as 'live usb windows xp' if by that you mean a 'test version' that you can run from usb before deciding whether to install - such as is available for Ubuntu and other distros. You should be able to do a full install of Windows XP to USB though, surely this is what you want?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want on the bootable USB?  A working XP?  An XP installer?

Comment: i want to create a live usb windows XP. It is like booting BackTrack from usb without installing it.I want the same think here with windows XP

Comment: See this link.  https://web.archive.org/web/20100926010118/http://www.ngine.de/index.jsp?pageid=4176